# Get number capital letters in a string using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, script, string, count

I have a string. For now lets go with `$string="mFN6jTPx?!"`. I would like to be able to count how many capital letters there are. I have tried using `($string -cmatch '[A-Z]').length` but that only comes back as 1 given it brings back true or false value. I have also tried using  `($string -creplace '^[A-Z]')` but it just brings back `mFN6jTPx?!` so doing length check will not get me the correct number. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really SharePoint related, but does this work?

```
($string.ToCharArray() |Where{$_ -cmatch '[A-Z]'}).count
```